# Handling json response from update in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, jquery

I'm just trying to understand just the basic response here.  I have an unedited controller method

```
  def update
    @ledgeritem = Ledgeritem.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ledgeritem.update_attributes(params[:ledgeritem])
        format.html { redirect_to @ledgeritem, :notice => 'Ledgeritem was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @ledgeritem.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/ledgeritems/" + id + ".json",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

My alert never shows, but the item does update.  What's the correct way to read and handle the json response?  I know this is a basic question, but I can't find any examples or information on this.

Comment: beware that `PUT` is not supported in all browsers for AJAX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, change

```
format.json { head :no_content }
```

to

```
format.json { render json: @ledgeritem }
```

`head :no_content` would just return the http code 204, which is to signify that there is no content on the page. You do not need this here.

Comment: My alert still doesn't show with this code, but I'm wondering if that's because the response I'm getting back is blank.  That's what kind of threw me when the update is successful it sends back a blank response.

Comment: Try changing `head :json => @ledgeritem` to `render :json => @ledgeritem`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code, that wasn't what was in there, it had head :no_content by default

Comment: Please try to specifically say this: `format.json { render json: @ledgeritem }`

Comment: @Charles no need to use `parseJSON` when `dataType:'json'` is set. jQUery will have already done it and `result` is already an object. This is documented in `$.ajax` API

Comment: I did that, that worked.  I guess I'm just not sure what the normal way to handle the json.

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, I didn't see that! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jhorra I updated my answer, now it should reflect the correct solution to your problem.